# Convert Word VBA macro to Libreoffice Write Basic

Tags: vba, ms-word, libreoffice, libreoffice-basic

Does anyone know the changes to be made to the vba macro code below, to save with LibreOffice Write every single mail merge record?
The code below, which works perfectly with Microsoft Word, creates a file in odt format for each surname record. Unfortunately it is not recognized by the basic LibreOffice package.
Thanks in advance.

```
sub save_all

On Error GoTo ErrH
Dim objWdMailMerge  As Word.MailMerge
Dim lngRecNum       As Long
Dim strPath         As String
Dim strFilename     As String
  Randomize
Dim n As Integer
n = 0
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  
    Set objWdMailMerge = ActiveDocument.MailMerge
  
    With objWdMailMerge
      .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
      With .DataSource
        .ActiveRecord = wdLastRecord
         lngRecNum = .ActiveRecord
        .ActiveRecord = wdFirstRecord
        Do
        n = n + 1
          .FirstRecord = .ActiveRecord
          .LastRecord = .ActiveRecord

             strFilename = .DataFields("Name").value
          If Len(strFilename) Then
           
            
            With ActiveDocument
              
              ChangeFileOpenDirectory "C:\Elaborazione\"
    
    ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:="MR " & strFilename & "-" & n & ".odt", FileFormat:= _
        wdFormatXMLDocumentMacroEnabled, LockComments:=False, Password:="", _
        AddToRecentFiles:=True, WritePassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, _
        EmbedTrueTypeFonts:=False, SaveNativePictureFormat:=False, SaveFormsData _
        :=False, SaveAsAOCELetter:=False
     
            End With
          
          End If
         If .ActiveRecord = lngRecNum Then Exit Do
          .ActiveRecord = wdNextRecord

        Loop
      End With
    End With
    
    MsgBox ("All records exported!"), vbInformation
    
ExitProc:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set objWdMailMerge = Nothing
    Exit Sub
    
ErrH:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume ExitProc

end sub
```

Comment: LibreOffice Basic and MS Word VBA only have some similarities but are entirely different languages. So there is no automatic translation nor can LibreOffice run Word code. The only way is to rewrite the entire code in LibreOffice Basic syntax manually. You have to do this yourself because nobody can do the work for you. If you get stuck during translation and run into a specific problem you can of course come back here and ask a question describing your specific problem.

Comment: *You must do it yourself* or [**see how it has been done many times by others**](https://ask.libreoffice.org/search?q=mail%20merge%20macro%20%23english%20tags%3Awriter).